# How do I combine multipe hook form alter functions

Tags: 8, forms

How can I combine multiple functions inside one hook form alter. If I try to use them separate I get the error Cannot redeclare mymod_form_alter()previously declared.

i want to combine this function

```
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

 function mymod_form_alter(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
 if ($form_id == 'node_page_form' || $form_id == 'node_page_edit_form') {

$form['uid']['widget'][0]['target_id']['#required'] = TRUE;
 }
   return $form;
}
```

and this function

```
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

function mymod_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, &$form_id) {
$form['field_short_description']['widget']['#after_build'][] = 

'_allowed_formats_remove_textarea_help';
}

function _allowed_formats_remove_textarea_help($form_element, FormStateInterface $form_state) 

{

  if (isset($form_element[0]['format'])) {
    // All this stuff is needed to hide the help text.
    unset($form_element[0]['format']['guidelines']);
    unset($form_element[0]['format']['help']);
    unset($form_element[0]['format']['#type']);
    unset($form_element[0]['format']['#theme_wrappers']);
    $form_element[0]['format']['format']['#access'] = FALSE;
  }
  return $form_element;
}
```

Comment: This needs to be tagged in Drupal 8

Answer (score 4):

You can do switch statements based on the form ID:

```
function hook_form_alter(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id)
{
  switch($form_id)
    case 'form_id_1':
      // Alter the form with an id of form_id_1
      break;
    case 'form_id_2':
      // Alter the form with an id of form_id_2
      break;
    case 'form_id_3':
      // Alter the form with an id of form_id_3
      break;
}
```